# Conteúdo de um site no aplicativo em Intel XDK

Tags: android, css, html5, script, intel

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo no Intel XDK no qual preciso publicar o conteúdo do site no aplicativo. Ou seja, quando eu atualizar o site, o conteúdo no aplicativo também seja atualizado. Lembrando que o site foi desenvolvido na plataforma Joomla! e é responsivo.

Exemplo: quero que os artigos do item de menu 'Notícias' do site seja publicado no aplicativo em uma página exclusiva de notícias.

Já tentei com a ferramenta iframe do Intel XDK, mas o que sai no aplicativo é toda a página do menu Notícias, inclusive com a barra lateral e o footer do site. Quero que saia apenas as notícias.

Já andei vendo alguma coisa na internet que também pode-se usar o rss feed por meio do Explore Services do Intel XDK, mas não sei irá funcionar, pois quero que sejam publicados tanto o texto quanto as imagens desses artigos.

Alguém tem uma ideia sobre isso?